# PHP Server responded "Forbidden" when trying to upload file from android

Tags: php, android

I try to run code from this site http://stunningco.de/2010/04/25/uploading-files-to-http-server-using-post-android-sdk/ but I have a problem, When I try to send file to server I get “Forbidden” response from server and on server is nothing. Do anyone know what is wrong with it? Maybe I need to change somethig in my php config? Thanks for every help.

Comment: how about a code sample?

Comment: Check the server's error log - should have the exact reason why the request is forbidden.

Comment: In error log is "client denied by server configuration: C:/wamp/www/zad1.php". Do you know what it mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excuse me in advance for my bad english. Your problem seems to be server related. Your configuration forbid you to upload the file. Maybe you should check your server file permissions. Check out this link as a step-stone in order to solve this issue : http://mysql-apache-php.com/fileupload-security.htm